# What function to hook for changes made in status and visibility of a post

Tags: plugin-development, functions, theme-development, hooks

I have a function to run every time a post is published or updated in anyway. Right now I am doing

```
function myFunction(){
   //Do Something
}    
add_filter('publish_post','myFunction');
add_filter('wp_update_post','myFunction');
```

Now, when I do this the function is getting called on when I publish a post or make any changes to the `Status: Draft/Pending Review` (as shown in the attached image), the function is not called. What function to hook to run my function on `Status` change?

[image]

**Got it to work. Answer below**

Comment: This is a filter of data, it does not alter the data saved. Do you wish to alter the saved data of the post?

Comment: I got the solution, I wanted to run a function whenever post status changed. I will update the solution so that it can help others

Comment: Awesome! I wanted to be sure that your wish was to `filter` data, rather than change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I was looking for was transition_post_status. The documentation can be found [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions).

What I did was to add one more filter `add_filter('transition_post_status','myFunction');`